# Adafruit minimqtt on Pi Pico H with Wiznet RP2040 ethernet hat "RuntimeError: Failed to establish connection."

Tags: raspberry-pi, mqtt, raspberry-pi-pico, adafruit-circuitpython

I'm trying to use the adafruit minimqtt library on a Pi Pico H, running circuitpython. I've been following [this guide](https://github.com/Wiznet/RP2040-HAT-CircuitPython/tree/master/examples/MQTT/Publish)
I'm using a mosquito broker on my windows 10 laptop and connecting directly through an ethernet cable to the Wiznet hat, as in the tutorial. The code I'm using is copied directly from [the example](https://github.com/Wiznet/RP2040-HAT-CircuitPython/blob/master/examples/MQTT/Publish/W5x00_MQTT_pub.py) with the following changes:

1. changed the IP address on line 22 to that of my windows machine
2. uncommneted lines 68 and 70, and commented out  line 73 to avoid using DHCP (someone else on the github has noted that the dhcp doesn't work). Also deleted the  extra space in line 70

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 84, in <module>
  File "/lib/adafruit_minimqtt/adafruit_minimqtt.py", line 441, in connect
  File "/lib/adafruit_minimqtt/adafruit_minimqtt.py", line 266, in _get_connect_socket
  File "/lib/adafruit_wiznet5k/adafruit_wiznet5k_socket.py", line 246, in connect
  File "/lib/adafruit_wiznet5k/adafruit_wiznet5k.py", line 570, in socket_connect
RuntimeError: Failed to establish connection.
```

I've looked through each of the scripts referenced and can't find any obvious errors (I'm not an expert in this so there might be something I've missed). I can't find anyone who's experienced this same error code, any help here would be appreciated.

- I've tried running the first half of the code (up to line 68), and then pinging the pico from my laptop. I've also pinged my laptop from the board. Both were successful, so I don't think it's a hardware issue.
- I've double checked that my broker is not in local mode. My .conf file contains

```
listener 1883
allow_anonymous true
```

and when I run mosquitto I get

```
C:\Users\me1xmtx\mosquitto>mosquitto -c rem.conf -v
1676306316: mosquitto version 2.0.15 starting
1676306316: Config loaded from rem.conf.
1676306316: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1676306316: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1676306316: mosquitto version 2.0.15 running
```

TCP (and UDP just in case) ports 1883 are open on the windows laptop

[image]

Comment: Just double checking, you have opened port 1883 on the Windows laptop?

Comment: Hi, I've double checked and the port is open, I've edited the original post to include an image